# How to use the DB connection config in java or groovy component?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have an requirement where i want to use the db connection configuration defined in mule config file.I want to use it in JAVA or Groovy code.
How i can do that?

Thanks,
Anurag Kumar Dwivedi

Answer (score 0):

That will depends if you have your mule app running ( MuleContext exists) or you want to parse the xml file and load the values... Assuming the first option, I just tested myself...

Mule XML configuration file :

```
<http:listener-config name="httpConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<flow name="muleloadconfigFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="httpConfig" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <component class="muleloadconfig.MuleLoadConfig" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

NOTE: config-ref="httpConfig"

Java Class:

```
public class MuleLoadConfig implements MuleContextAware, Callable {

MuleContext localContext;

@Override
public void setMuleContext(MuleContext context) {
    this.localContext = context;
}

public String returnConfigClassName() {
    return localContext.getRegistry().get("httpConfig").getClass().toString();
}


@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("printing config Class: " + returnConfigClassName());
    return "ok";
}}
```

Result in the console:

> printing config Class: class org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListenerConfig

Not sure if this is what you are looking for as you didn't provide any details in your use case...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In java you could pattern it like this.

```
  <component>
     <singleton-object class="com.alex.v1.jdbc.SQLServerSPExecutor">
        <property key="dataSource" value="" value-ref="SData_Source"/>
      </singleton-object>
  </component>


  public class SQLServerSPExecutor implements Callable {
      private DataSource dataSource;

      public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
          this.dataSource = dataSource;
      }

      @Override
      public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex it was quite helpful.